# Sending apps to other devices

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

How can I share my app with friends? I created my app in eclipse and can run the app on my device but how can I share it without adding it to the play market?

Comment: Who's method did you use? You should vote that one for a best answer for future viewers who may have this problem

Answer (score 1):

Send your apk file to your friend in mail or send it via bluetooth then follow below step.

- Copy the APK file to your Android’s sdcard in your phone.
- Download and install the Apps Installer application from the Android
  Market
- Once installed, the Apps Installer will display the APK files on the
  memory card.
- Click and install your APK files.

**Note : You can find your apk file in project's bin folder. but before this you have to enable unknow Source . Got to Settings -> Applications -> and Enable Unknown Sources.**

Comment: But How can i get apk files from my device?

Comment: @user1171194 As i note you can find it from project's bin folder from your eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 1):

You can share the `.apk` file that is created (usually in a sub folder of the `out` folder).
Just send your .apk file to your friends via email, bluetooth etc.

Answer (score 1):

Run the app on the emulator to test it. Now Eclipse should have created a bin folder in your project folder. In this folder you will find an apk file that contains your app.

Just send this file to your friend via email. He can now install the file on the emulator if he has one running. If not he can just plugin his phone via usb move the file to the SD-Card remove the USB connection and then navigate to the file on his SD-Card with a file browser like [ASTRO](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-metago-astro-qzq.aspx) and select the, item now the application manager should show up and he can install the app. If this does not work he has to go to settings -> applications -> and enable unknown sources.